# Oracle -- WITH CLAUSE => MERGE? (Syntax error, )

Tags: oracle, merge, with-statement, ora-00928, subquery-factoring

I'm trying to get the WITH clause to work with merge in Oracle, but for some reason I can't get it working. I'm sure it is something obvious, but I just haven't seen it.

```
-- behold, the wonders of fake data
WITH X AS ( 
SELECT 
  'moo' AS COW, 
  'woof' AS CAT, 
  (SELECT MAX( DECIBELS ) FROM ANIMALIA WHERE COW = 'moo' ) AS DECIBELS
FROM DUAL )
MERGE INTO ANIMALIA D 
USING X
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET D.COW = X.COW;
```

### EDIT

I actually found out how to manage this (before I submitted the question), but I think that since it took me quite some time to find the answer, hopefully leaving this question up will mean that the next person will find it in not quite so much time.

I will post the answer in a day or so, but if someone else posts it in the meanwhile they'll get the points.

Comment: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Comment: Actually, the subquery did not have anything to do with the problem in the end.

Comment: @OMG I can answer this and mark it as such, but if someone knows off-hand, they might appreciate the points, you know? (Any thoughts on the topic?)

Comment: @OMG I can send it to you if you like.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can't use the WITH clause anywhere but in a SELECT statement.  [See the documentation here.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2077142):

> You can specify this clause in any top-level SELECT statement and in
>   most types of subqueries.

So, you can do something like this (11g tested):

```
MERGE INTO animalia d
USING (WITH X AS 
       (SELECT  'moo' AS COW, 'woof' AS CAT, 
                (SELECT MAX( DECIBELS ) 
                   FROM ANIMALIA 
                  WHERE COW = 'moo' ) AS DECIBELS
          FROM DUAL )
       SELECT * FROM X) q ON (1 = 1)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET d.cow = q.cow||' and more';
```

Comment: Thanks. Happy points. My solution was `USING (SELECT... ) X ON`, but I think both do the same thing.

Comment: Sure, I thought the exercise was to use the WITH clause in a MERGE statement ;-)

Comment: Honestly, I didn't care terribly much once I got it working, but I'm really glad that we have both syntax's here (for the next guy)

Comment: But you still can't use source inline view in `WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE` :(