# How can I save computation by reusing calculated result set in MERGE

Tags: sql, vertica

I would like to reuse previously calculated result set in SQL join statement that I need to run daily. As an example, I have two tables: table_A and table_B and they share a common key, say, `ckey`.  I would like to use LEFT JOIN in my query like this to find the data records in table_A that maps to the ones in table_B based on `ckey`:

```
SELECT a*, b*
FROM table_A as A
LEFT JOIN table_B as B
ON A.ckey = B.ckey
```

But then I would like to store the unmatched rows in the above join in a separate table, say `table_C`, so that I can review them periodically and update table_B content later. For the ones that match between table_A and table_B, I would like to store them in a new table (let's call it, table_C). To do that, I was hoping to use WITH clause to temporarily store the result sets like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_C (ckey_to_review VARCHAR(10));

WITH left_join_result AS(
SELECT a*, b.ckey as b_ckey
FROM table_A as A
LEFT JOIN table_B as B
ON A.ckey = B.ckey),

non_matchable_data AS(
SELECT distinct ckey
FROM left_join_result AS C
WHERE b_ckey IS NULL),

matchable_data AS(
SELECT *
FROM left_join_result AS C
WHERE b_ckey IS NOT NULL)

/* use MERGE to upsert newly found unmatchable items */
MERGE INTO table_C AS t
USING non_matchable_data AS s
ON t.ckey_to_review = s.ckey
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ckey_to_review = s.ckey
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (ckey_to_review)
    VALUES (s.ckey)

/* then use data from 'matchable_data' above for something other procedures */
```

I learned later that [WITH clause are only allowed to be used with SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673806/oracle-with-clause-merge-syntax-error). To provide more specific context, I am using Vertica to do this in case there is some Vertica-specific solution to this problem. I possess just the basic knowledge of SQL, so I am sure there is a design pattern of some sort which could guide me to do what I'm trying to do efficiently (that is, **not requiring me to call LEFT JOIN more than once and reuse the result set from the LEFT JOIN again and again**).

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I think you are overthinking it.

So to answer your question exactly, you can just create local temp tables instead of using `with`. [`CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/CREATETEMPORARYTABLE.htm) and it will be available in your session. And by the way, unless you [specifically enable an option](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AnalyzingData/Queries/WITHClausesInSELECT.htm), `with` is an inline view, not materialized.

That said, really I imagine that the following would be fine.  And if you really want it to be efficient, then you'll be more concerned with how the data is segmented and sorted to create local merge joins.

```
SELECT ckey
FROM table_B
MINUS
SELECT ckey
FROM table_A
```

and

```
SELECT ckey
FROM table_B
INTERSECT
SELECT ckey
FROM table_A
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try using local temp table. The reason I'm concerned with the code's efficiency is because there are about 500m rows of data everyday to be processed. But you are right that the way data is segmented is probably more important than the join code itself. Thank you!

Comment: Can this not be done with an 'insert/ignore or insert... on duplicate key update' style setup? the first time will be a heavy process but going forward only new items would be added. I guess it also depends on your flavor of sql since minus is not an option on Mysql.

Comment: @cora no such thing as insert ignore in Vertica. Vertica is a columnar, OLAP style database without those features.

Answer (score 1):

So what you're looking is common in the DataWarehouse (or DataMart) world... you are looking for an INCREMENTAL load strategy, of which there are several approaches.

```
insert into [matched] (PK)
select key from table1 join table2 on key
where key not in (select PK from [Matched])
```

first time it's gonna be a doozie, based on your comment about 500m records... incremental should be less so.

you may also consider various additional strategies:

- nolocks (depending how the source tables are populated) to reduce lock contention
- chunking to reduce transaction size (log file growth, etc)
- maxdop to manage throughput vs execution time vs resource load

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! :)